# iOS xcode 11 new project multiple errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

[image]

Haven't worked on iOS in almost a year. Now trying to create an xcode project from my mac, running into a whole host of issues. Old project that were previously working are also not working on xcode 11. Googling individual errors yields no positive results.

`xcodebuild -version` = Xcode 11.1 Build version 11A1027

`/usr/bin/swiftc --version` = Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default template file when creating a new project in Xcode with swiftUI would be like the one below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

And it would build properly. But in the screenshot you provided above, it is not the same and it has many errors as shown in the IDE. Can you try with the code above and make sure if the problem still persist. Cheers.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!